# Form redirects to non existing page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form and some php to it. 
Whenever i press submit the form redirects me to a non existing page. 404 page to be exact. What i want is this link when the form is submitted:  `header("Location: https://test.com/?add-to-cart=$values")` Any idea why this happens?

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product[]" value="12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product[]" value="13">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product3" name="product[]" value="14">
  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['product'])){
    $values =  implode(',',$_POST['product']);
    // header("Location: https://test.com/?add-to-cart=$values");
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: This probably has something to do with the URL rewrite rules that wordpress uses. Your URL would normally expand to `http://test.com/index.php?add-to-cart=$values` but since the URL doesn't literally match an existing file, it gets rewritten to whatever Wordpress uses. Try using `header("Location: https://test.com/index.php?add-to-cart=$values");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should submit forms using the Admin-Post or Admin-Ajax urls and not to the own page, please check some references below:

"Handling Form Submissions in WordPress with Admin-Post and Admin-Ajax" - https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/

"WordPress form submission the right way" - https://blog.josedasilva.net/wordpress-form-submission-the-right-way/

Hope it clarifies the process of form submission on Wordpress.

Cheers
Jose